# SQLServer on existing update

Tags: sql-server, database, migration, sqlanywhere

We are planning to convert an application from Sybase SQL Anywhere to SQL Server.

At SA we use a lot of "on existing update", that checks by primary key, if line exists.
If true, is update (in same way if I was executing update clause).
If not, it inserts.

Does SQL Server supports something like this?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no support for this in one command. And the best way I found was follow [Jeremiah Clark's tip](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2008/02/17/sql-if-exists-update-else-insert.aspx): try to update, then check for the number of affected records. If it was zero, then I insert:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET (...) WHERE Column1='SomeValue'
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
    INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (...)
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to avoid tests. But if it does not have, probably I'll use this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you will use SQL Server 2008 and later, you can use MERGE command. You can find description here:

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625(SQL.100).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625%28SQL.100%29.aspx)

If you use older SQL,  **Jeremiah Clark's** solution suggested by **Erick Sasse**  will be ok.

Comment: Yes, we are using 2008 R2. I'll discuss this command with my team. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has all the features of an high-end RDBMS, Stored Procedures, Triggers, UDF and so on... as you probably know MS SQL Server was branched out exactly from Sybase so they do have common roots.

I am not sure I get your question completely, of course you can have a SQL Statement which contains some logic and does INSERT or UPDATE depending on some conditions or if a record was already found, TSQL is the SQL dialect of SQL Server and supports this and much more.

If you really have a specific question or doubt on a statement please show us your statement as you have it right now in SA.

Comment: insert into TableA (id, value1, value2) on existing update values (1, 'ABC', 123);

Comment: if TableA have a line with id (pk) equals 1, it will update. If not, it will insert.

Comment: FYI SQL Server was branched from Sybase __ASE__. Sybase SQL Anywhere is a completely different RDBMS that has no code in common with ASE.